# Confusion in adding an element to a sorted list of integers

Tags: c, linked-list

In the problem we want to write a recursive C function that adds a node to a sorted linked list. I am trying to understand the solution which is:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int V;
    struct Node *Next;
} Node;

void Insert_R(Node **F, int x)
{ 
    Node *P;
    if(*F == NULL || (*F)->V > x)
    {
        P = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        P->V = x;
        P->Next = *F;
       *F = P;
    }
    else
        Insert_R(&(*F)->Next, x);
}
```

What I understood: call the first element containing an integer greater than x Node 2 and Node 1 its predecessor. So we want to add a new node before Node 2 and after Node 1. So the Next pointer of the new node must point to the current position of `*F` which is at Node 2.

But in this case how did we manage to let the Next pointer in Node 1 point to the new node?

Comment: As for a possible way to understand what's happening, use pen and paper to draw your initial list (using squares as the nodes, and arrows as the pointers). Also draw (and for each recursive call erase and redraw) an arrow for `F` *and* `*F`, where it points in each call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried drawing but one question remained: when *F is pointing to Node2, is saying Node1->Next=P equivalent to *F=P since the next element of Node1 points to Node2 and to *F?

Comment: I think you should compare with `(*F)->Next->V` and not with `(*F)->V`

Comment: @OrestisZekai when I tried solving it I really wrote this and in the if statement I wrote P->Next=*F->Next and *F->Next=P. But when I saw the solution written by the professor I wanted to understand it so this is not my code.

Comment: This bit `&(*F)->Next` in the recursive call actually calls it with a _pointer_ to the member field `Next`, which can then be modified - personally, I don't like it even if it works.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError should it be written as: &(*F->Next)?

Comment: @user7857462 No, `&(*F->Next)` won't compile because by the operator precedence rules, that is equivalent to `&(*(F->Next))` and `F` does not have type `Node *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `F` is a pointer to a pointer to a Node.

Things might be clearer with this figure:

```
      Node1 {
        V
 F ---> Next ----> Node2 {
      }              V
                     Next
                   }
```

As you see, F is a pointer on the field Next of the previous Node. If `*F` is NULL, the end of list is reached and a node may be inserted. The value in `*F` is assigned to the field `Next` of the new node. The address of the new node is stored in `*F` which is the field `Next` of Node1.

The new node will thus be "inserted" after Node1 and "before" whatever is after it, NULL or Node2.

Note that it works also when starting the insertion. We pass the address of `head` instead of the address of the field `Next` of the previous block. The nice thing is that the code of the function remains the same. By testing `*F` we test the content of `head`. If it’s NULL (the list is empty), we create a new node and store its address in `*F` which is `head`.

By making `F` a pointer to a pointer to a node, we have an elegant way to insert a node in a list. It also works for deletion.